# Set timer for trafic light in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to set a timer with two Button for my trafic Light.
One button for start.
another one for stop.

I want that when ever user clicked on start button then Trafic light start to working and change his color, and when ever user clicked stop then Trafic light also stop working.
I have a code which is working just Automaticly and not with button. ( circles automaticly change his color even when user not click on any button)

How can i set the buttons for that duty ?

```html
<button id="btn1">start</button>
<button id="btn2">stop</button>
    <div id="div1"></div>
        <div id="div2"></div>
        <div id="div3"></div>


        <script>
           
            const btn1=document.getElementById("btn1");
            const btn2=document.getElementById("btn2");
            const div1=document.getElementById("div1");
            const div2=document.getElementById("div2");
            const div3=document.getElementById("div3");
            
            
            btn1.addEventListener("click",timerSet)
            let timer= setInterval(timerSet,1500);
            

            function timerSet(){

    if(div1.style.backgroundColor=="red"){

    div2.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
    div1.style.backgroundColor="black";
    div3.style.backgroundColor="black";



}
else if(div2.style.backgroundColor=="yellow"){
    div3.style.backgroundColor="green";
    div2.style.backgroundColor="black";
    div1.style.backgroundColor="black";

}
else if (div3.style.backgroundColor=="green"){
    div1.style.backgroundColor="red";
    div3.style.backgroundColor="black";
}
                


            }
            

            

            
            Kreis(div1,20,"red");
            Kreis(div2,20,"black");
            Kreis(div3,20,"black");


            function Kreis(element,radius,farbe){

            element.style.backgroundColor=farbe;
            element.style.width=2*radius+"px";
            element.style.height=2*radius+"px";
            element.style.borderRadius=2*radius+"px";

}



            </script>
```

Comment: `timer= setInterval(timerSet,1500);` should be in the click event if you want it to happen only then

Comment: it is, i wrote: btn1.addEventListener("click",timerSet).@PatrickEvans

Comment: That is you setting a event listener, that is not the same as moving your `setInterval` into a click event listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your `setInterval` statement into your event listener. At the moment you have it in global space meaning it will run right away.

```
btn1.addEventListener("click",startTimer)
let timer= null;
function startTimer(){
    timer = setInterval(timerSet,1500);
}

function timerSet(){
   /* ... */
}
```

To stop you just put a `clearInterval` call in another click listener

```
btn2.addEventListener('click',stopTimer);
function stopTimer(){
    clearInterval(timer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> //if you want to clear stop the light ==>  add this code to stop function `document.querySelector(".show").classList.remove("show")`

```js
const start = document.querySelector("#start");
const stop = document.querySelector("#stop");
const lights = document.querySelectorAll(".light");
var i = 0;
var trafic;
start.onclick = () => {
  trafic = setInterval(() => {
    var currentShowing = document.querySelector(".show");
    if (currentShowing) {
      currentShowing.classList.remove("show");
    }
    lights[i].classList.add("show");
    i == 2 ? (i = 0) : i++;
  }, 1000);
};

stop.onclick = () => {
  clearInterval(trafic);
  //if you want to clear stop the light ==> document.querySelector(".show").classList.remove("show")
};
```

```css
      .container-traficlight {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 0.2rem;
        margin-top: 1rem;
      }

      .container-traficlight .light {
        position: relative;
        width: 2rem;
        height: 2rem;
        background-color: #010101;
        border-radius: 50%;
        filter: brightness(0%);
      }
      .container-traficlight .light.red {
        background-color: red;
      }
      .container-traficlight .light.orange {
        background-color: orange;
      }
      .container-traficlight .light.green {
        background-color: green;
      }
      .container-traficlight .light.show {
        filter: brightness(100%) !important;
      }
```

```html
 <button id="start">Start</button>
 <button id="stop">Stop</button>
  <div class="container-traficlight">
      <div class="light red"></div>
      <div class="light orange"></div>
      <div class="light green"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, I hope You will be satisfied. Best regards;)

```js
const btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
const btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
const div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
const div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
const div3 = document.getElementById("div3");

let timer = null;

btn1.addEventListener("click", startTimer);
btn2.addEventListener("click", stopTimer);

function timerSet() {
  if (div1.style.backgroundColor == "red") {
    div2.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    div1.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    div3.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  } else if (div2.style.backgroundColor == "yellow") {
    div3.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    div2.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    div1.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  } else if (div3.style.backgroundColor == "green") {
    div1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    div3.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  }
}

function Kreis(element, radius, farbe) {
  element.style.backgroundColor = farbe;
  element.style.width = 2 * radius + "px";
  element.style.height = 2 * radius + "px";
  element.style.borderRadius = 2 * radius + "px";
}

function startTimer() {
  timer = setInterval(timerSet, 1500);
  Kreis(div1, 20, "red"), Kreis(div2, 20, "black"), Kreis(div3, 20, "black");
}

function stopTimer() {
  clearInterval(timer);
}
```

```html
<button id="btn1">start</button>
<button id="btn2">stop</button>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
```